# How to view Kotlin platform dependent (expect) source code in IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Update: Known IDEA issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-10228. Thanks @somethingsomething for the pointer.

I'm learning Kotlin and in [one of the examples](https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/02_control_flow/02_Loops), there's the following code:

`listOf("carrot", "cheese", "chocolate")`

Putting it in IDEA and following up `listOf` source (control/command + click) leads to:

[image]

Which is very nice. I can see actual source code and learn from the origin. But!!!

When further clicking on `asList` leads to:

[image]

But here, there's no source code. Dead end :(

The `expect` keyword means that the actual implementation is platform dependent.

**Is there a way to look up the code, connecting it to IDEA? For example, if I'm on a Mac, how do I see the local implementation and connect it to IDEA using control/command + click?** Thanks.

I've searched for similar questions in SO. Found some related to dependency definitions in pom to see the source code instead of decompiled code. My problem is different. I actually see the source code - not any decompiled code. My specific problem is that not all source code is shown. Specifically missing the platform dependent source code.

IDEA version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-221.5591.52, built on May 10, 2022
```

Comment: It sounds like the navigation should take you to the actual implementation for your target platform https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-navigate-from-expect-declarations-to-actual-implementations/10701/3 but it indeed doesn't here. This sounds like a bug to me, but I'm not too familiar with this. Fwiw, you can find the actual by searching for the file `_ArraysJvm.kt`, which i got from here: https://proandroiddev.com/the-mystery-of-mutable-kotlin-collections-e82cbf5d781.

Comment: Yeah, Ctrl+clicking takes me directly to the Jvm implementation. I don't know what about the project configuration would affect this.